# Finding how long a particular DOM element took to load

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript utility that tells the user the number of 3rd party links embedded into a web page. I'd like to be able to give metrics on how long they took to load (and possibly payload size) much like FireBug, but I don't know if I can get at this information using raw JS.

The consumers of this tool are business people who won't be running Firefox, or understand firebug etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery you can hook into the load event on all images then record the difference in time between $(document).ready and the current time.  That'll give you some benchmarks to work from.

For Example, the following should log the # of ms it took each image to load (from the moment the dom was ready):

```
$(function() {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();

  $("img").load(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(this.src + " " + (currentTime-startTime));
  });
});
```